# How do I stop making the same typo over and over again?

Tags: typing, touch-typing

I learned how to touch type 13 or 14 years ago and I rarely make mistakes. However, lately I've been making the same mistake over and over again. When I have to type *io* I'll often type *oi* instead. How can I get rid of this error/habit?

I'm thinking of practising with words containing *io* and *oi* like when I learned how to touch type. Perhaps there are other effective methods?

Comment: The only way to learn a skill is by repeating the process, this allows you to, do something without even thinkinkg about it.  This is how basketball players are able to hit a high percentage of their baskets, while they do have skill to a certain degree, some of it is simply muscle memory.

Comment: Could it be the music you're listening to most of the time? oi oi oi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type it correctly until your muscles have learned the right pattern. Start slowly and increase the speed, concentrating on getting it right every time.

A good way to build repetition into your daily routine is to put the letter sequence into your password. If you add it on to the password you would have used anyway, it won't make it more guessable.

Comment: The password thing is a good idea, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's harder to make typing mistakes when you use a split layout keyboard like the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard. Because of the split keyboard layout and the Braille dots on the <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd> keys, your fingers know exactly where they are on the keyboard even in the dark, which makes touch typing faster and more accurate.

Comment: Not sure if such a keyboard would help in my case (*i* and *o* are right next to each other and I'm typing them in the wrong order), but a helpful answer in general.

Comment: The **I** key is located on top and adjacent to the **J** key which is a Braille dot key on the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard. If there us any doubt about which key it is, just rub your finger on the Braille dot on the letter **J**.

Comment: The problem isn't that I don't know which key is where, it's that I type them in the wrong order against my will. I know that *i* is at the left and *o* is at the right, yet my fingers type *oi*. Apologies if my question was a bit unclear, I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Stijn - So retrain your muscle memory

Comment: @Ramhound I will, I did read your comment and Peter's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are certain `oi` words that you mis-type, you can also use a key expander program to fix those on a case-by-case basis. I have `amil` set to auto-replace with `mail`, `mroe`->`more` , `coudl`->`could`, etc. (But this might just reinforce your habits instead of re-training!)